# In Plesk server by mistake deleted domain

Tags: vps, plesk

I deleted in my CentOs VPS 1 domain accidentally and i have no backup.. is it possible to restore the domain and the DB by server side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a daily database backup, which you could restore. Consider to have a look at "/var/lib/psa/dumps", where you will find the backups.

A documentation/tutorial from Plesk how you would restore the backup could be found here:

**=>** [How to backup/restore a Plesk database dump? *( Official Plesk - KB - article 213904125 )*](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213904125)

Comment: this will restore the whole server? how do i restore only 1 domain?

Comment: Well, sorry, David, but YOU deleted possible backups ( either manually, or automatically local created ones ), when you deleted the domain over your Plesk Control Panel. If you don't have an external backup ( i.e. placed on a FTP - backup - location ), you will not have the possibility to restore the domains DB and it's content.